# Sort model based on count of nested relationship - Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have three tables `categories`, `courses`, and `users`.

`courses` and `users` table has intermediate table `user_courses`.

They have following relationships

**Category Model**

```
public function courses()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Course::class, 'category_id', 'id');
}
```

**Course Model**

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id', 'id');
}

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_courses', 'course_id', 'user_id');
}
```

Now I want all categories with courses which has users and these categories should be order by `users_count` in descending order.

Is there any eloquent way of achieving it?

Comment: You can use `withCount` and then use it as `order by`. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models

Comment: I want count of nested relationship i.e. `users` then categories has to be sorted based on this count i.e. `users_count`

Comment: `withCount` is used for that with a `hasManyThrough` relationship like @Anrut Chapanond used it in his answer

Answer (score 3):

You should define a `hasManyThrough` relationship in your `Category` model.

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(User::class, Course::class);
}
```

Then you can sort your user count with the following

```
Category::with('courses.users')
    ->withCount(['users' => function($query) {
        $query->orderBy('users_count', 'desc');
    }])
    ->get();
```

Comment: upvote because solution was to use `hasManyThrough` relationship but I have different table structure than one goes with your relationship.